# Blank preloader before my ng-view is loaded

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

I know there are a lot of questions regarding this, but a lot of them are old (some doesn't work anymore with the new Angular version) and others are not related to what I'm trying to achieve.

Basically I have an ng-view:

```
<main class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2 bg-body">
   <div ng-view></div>                       
</main>
```

in which I display data after an `http.get` done with routing and partials. As written in the title I would like to display a blank (white) page inside the `ng-view` with a spinner ( `<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>` ) in the center while my data are loading.

I tryed with a directive, but it seems not working:

AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['plangular','ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'slick']);

app.directive('loading', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace:true,
        template: '<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
              scope.$watch('loading', function (val) {
                  if (val)
                      $(element).show();
                  else
                      $(element).hide();
              });
        }
      }
});
```

HTML:

```
<main class="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2 bg-body">           
    <loading></loading>
    <div ng-view></div>                        
</main>
```

What could be the best approach?

Comment: Where it goes wrong? What actually happens?

Comment: Are you getting the loader or not?

Comment: Well, not sure why this is not working (am I forgotting something?)... here is my site: http://new.wearegoingsolo.com/tracks/paperwhite-wash-us-away

Comment: can you make a plunker?

Comment: @GoingSolo, Does it show the spinner or not?

Comment: It doesn't. Nothing is showed.

Answer (score 0):

Do this and replace `/home`route with your template and do not remove `ng-if` in `/home` template and it must be your home page

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-router@1.4.0-beta.3" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main ng-controller="mainCtrl">
      <loading ng-if="showSpin"></loading>
      <div ng-view="" ng-if="!showSpin"></div>
      <!--<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>-->
    </main>
  </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

// Code goes here

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($rootScope,$scope, $timeout) {
        $rootScope.showSpin = true;

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
      $timeout(function(){$rootScope.showSpin = true;
      $scope.showSpin = true;}, 5000); // Just addedto show loader, you can remove the `$timeout`
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
      $timeout(function(){$rootScope.showSpin = false;
      $scope.showSpin = false;}, 5000); // Just addedto show loader, you can remove the `$timeout`
    });
})
.directive('loading', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$watch('showSpin', function(newVal) {
                if (newVal)
                    $(element).show();
                else
                    $(element).hide();
            });
        }
    }
})
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            url: '/home',
            template: '<div>Hello world!</div>',
            controller: function($scope) {
            }
        })
        .when('/example', {
            url: '/example',
            template: '<div>Hello Example!</div>',
            controller: function($scope) {
            }
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/example' })
})
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**
I have updated the answer. Please check

Working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/oRa4vZlYTzSYIPSc21P0?p=preview)

Comment: Please make a plunker with just the spinner and a route(state).

Comment: Can I link you to the js script?

Comment: Still I guess I not explained myself, that was just a test, I dont want to show a spinner at the top of the content, I want to display a blank white page with a spinner inside it, while the content is loading

Comment: Yes, I am doing

Comment: Oh, thanks, sorry my english is not good, thought I didn't explain myself. Here is the script http://new.wearegoingsolo.com/wp-content/themes/GoingSolo/js/scripts.js it's kinda hard to replicate this issue in a plunker

Comment: Tryed to adapt your code to my routing, but it seems not working as expected. It works if you refresh the page, but it's not working when you move inside the site: http://new.wearegoingsolo.com/tracks/paperwhite-wash-us-away try to move inside (try to click next or previous in the right sidebar)

Comment: Do you want to make it appear on each route?

Comment: Yes in each route, but I've update the controller of my content with the two variable as false, but it doesn't work

Comment: I updated my answer. Now, it will work for every route. Check it once.

Comment: Uhm, this still not working if you try to nav in the posts (next and previous in the right sidebar) http://new.wearegoingsolo.com/tracks/gems-forgive-me

Comment: Once the route already visited, there is no need to show a loader because the content will not load from server. It just load from the history/cache. If you want to load it from the server means you are slowing down your app

Comment: I would like to achieve something like this http://www.hillydilly.com/2017/05/jerry-folk-money/ (try to move inside). the fact is that my content is loaded in a ugly way, cause it load the html first the then data

Comment: So, in that case have a loader service, write the logic to show loader and when there is an ajax call show the loader and when the request is success then hide the loader. i can't do it now